# Command Line arguments - PHP

Tags: php, command-line, arguments

Am trying the following php script which finds out the maximum between 2 numbers, it accepts the arguments through command line. I check whether the input is provided right, based on the number of command line arguments.

```
<?php   
function larger($arg1,$arg2) {
    return max($arg1,$arg2);
}

if($argc > 3 || $argc < 3) print 'Invalid Arguments'; exit(1); 
if($argc==3) {
    print larger($argv[1],$argv[2]);
}

?>
```

Am executing the program in a windows system, and the file resides in xampp/php directory. While executing I don't get any output neither any error report. How do i check whether am right or wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exit(1)` will always be called since it's outside of that if statement.  Try this:

```
<?php   
function larger($arg1,$arg2) {
   return max($arg1,$arg2);
}

if($argc > 3 || $argc < 3) {
    print 'Invalid Arguments'; 
    exit(1); 
} else {
    print larger($argv[1],$argv[2]);
    exit(0);
}
```